# Using data frame column with character list as name of variables for function in for loop putting results in variable

Tags: r, loops, variables, get

I want to know how to use a data frame column with a character list as name of variables for function in for loop putting results in variable.

I want to use the `mtcars` dataset variables `mpg`, `drat`, `disp` as DVs, and then generate means from them.

I created a data frame with just those names as a a column:

```
mtcars_DVs <- data.frame(c("mpg", "drat", "disp"))
names(mtcars_DVs)[names(mtcars_DVs) == "c..mpg....drat....disp.."] <- "Variable_name"
mtcars_DVs$Variable_name <- as.character(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name)
```

I want to create a column in the called `Variable_means` with the means of those DVs using a for loop that references the `mtcars_DVs$Variable_name` as the name of the objects used to create the mean value.

This output is 1 method that does not work:

```
> mtcars_DVs$Variable_means <- 
+   for (DV_col in mtcars_DVs$Variable_name) 
+   {
+     (mean(mtcars$DV_col))
+   }
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(mtcars$DV_col) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(mtcars$DV_col) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(mtcars$DV_col) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

This output is another method that does not work:

```
> mtcars_DVs$Variable_means <- 
+   for (DV_col in mtcars_DVs$Variable_name) 
+   {
+     (mean(as.name(mtcars$DV_col)))
+   }
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
```

Another unsuccessful output:

```
> mtcars_DVs$Variable_means <- 
+   for (DV_col in mtcars_DVs$Variable_name) 
+   {
+     (mean(get(mtcars$DV_col)))
+   }
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': invalid first argument
```

I could do this the long way, but that is time consuming and not self referencing:

```
# generates means
> mean(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 20.09062
> mean(mtcars$drat)
[1] 3.596563
> mean(mtcars$disp)
[1] 230.7219

# inputs means
> mtcars_DVs$Variable_means <- c("20.09062", "3.596563", "230.7219")

# displays data
> mtcars_DVs
  Variable_name Variable_means
1           mpg       20.09062
2          drat       3.596563
3          disp       230.7219
```

Please help. I'm happy to switch methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the column 'Variable_name', extract the ccolumn from the data as a `vector` with `[[` and get the `mean`

```
mtcars_DVs$Variable_means <- sapply(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name, 
        function(nm) mean(mtcars[[nm]]))
```

---

Using `$` on the object literally checks for a column name "DV_col", instead it would be

```
mtcars[[DV_col]]
```

Also, the assignment in `for` loop would be

```
mtcars_DVs$Variable_means <- numeric(nrow(mtcars_DVs))
for(i in seq_along(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name)) {
         mtcars_DVs$Variable_means[i] <-  
                 mean(mtcars[[mtcars_DVs$Variable_name[i]]])
 } 

mtcars_DVs
#  Variable_name Variable_means
#1           mpg      20.090625
#2          drat       3.596563
#3          disp     230.721875
```

---

Also, there is vectorized `colMeans`, so we can just do

```
mtcars_DVs$Variable_means <- colMeans(mtcars[mtcars_DVs$Variable_name])
```

---

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 mtcars %>% 
   summarise(across(all_of(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name), mean)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'Variable_name',
         values_to = 'Variable_means')
 # A tibble: 3 x 2
 #  Variable_name Variable_means
 # <chr>                  <dbl>
 #1 mpg                    20.1 
 #2 drat                    3.60
 #3 disp                  231.
```

---

Or with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
qTBL(fmean(get_vars(mtcars, mtcars_DVs$Variable_name)), 
      keep.attr = TRUE, row.names.col = 'Variable_name')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Variable_name      X
#  <chr>          <dbl>
#1 mpg            20.1 
#2 drat            3.60
#3 disp          231.
```